# Can't hover over jquery toggled submenu

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I built a menu with jquery, 4 category buttons on the top menu triggering 4 submenus below. It works fine, the submenus are appearing and changing when I hover over another button, but I can't hover over the submenu, it's dissappearing when I "leave" the trigger button.

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/2zrjzdy3/) (sorry for the messy code, I can't reproduce the entire composition in Fiddle, I copy-pasted the important parts and the issue is same on the site as seen on this example)

This is the jquery for the submenu calls:
('active' and 'rotated' is for changing icons/rotating the text on the trigger buttons, these are triangles and I did some jquery fanciness to them, I hope it's still understandable)

```
 $('.leisuremenu').hover(function () {
    $('.leisure_menu').toggleClass('show_menu');
    $('.luxury_menu').toggleClass('show_menu');
    $('.select-luxury').toggleClass('active');
    $('.select-corporate').toggleClass('rotated');
    $('.select-luxury').toggleClass('rotated');
});
$('.corporatemenu').hover(function () {
    $('.corporate_menu').toggleClass('show_menu');
    $('.luxury_menu').toggleClass('show_menu');
    $('.select-luxury').toggleClass('active');
    $('.select-luxury').toggleClass('rotated');
});
$('.vipmenu').hover(function () {
    $('.vip_menu').toggleClass('show_menu');
    $('.luxury_menu').toggleClass('show_menu');
    $('.select-luxury').toggleClass('active');
    $('.select-vip').toggleClass('rotated');
    $('.select-vip').toggleClass('active');
});
```

In this example the 4th trigger button is active, the other 3 is triggering the other 3 submenu.

How can I modify this to achieve the submenus staying in place when I hover over them AND it should be dissapearing when I leave the submenu or hover over another trigger button?

(note: there is no space between the trigger triangles and the submenus, so I don't think it's a CSS issue)

I've tried adding this but it didn't work:

```
        $('.vip_menu').hover(function () {
            $('.vip_menu').toggleClass('show_menu');
        });
        $('.corporate_menu').hover(function () {
            $('.corporate_menu').toggleClass('show_menu');
        });
        $('.leisure_menu').hover(function () {
            $('.leisure_menu').toggleClass('show_menu');
        });
```

Let me know if I need to clarify more details/code.

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Could you add your HTML? Or even better, put your html, css and javascript in http://jsfiddle.net and reproduce the problem?

Comment: Edited, added Fiddle example, not exactly the same code (I have lots of not important css modifications) but looks like the same issue I'm having on the site.

Answer (score 0):

The [`hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) function of jQuery lets you give one or two functions. If you provide both, the first is executed on `mouseenter` and the second is executed on `mouseleave`. If you only provide one, the function is called on both events, which is why it is toggling the class again. Since you only want this to happen when you enter, you can just change `hover(...)` to `mouseenter(...)`. However, you can do a bit of cleanup to just have one function handle all your events, instead of a separate function for each menu.

I changed your markup slightly to just add a `menu` class to each of the menus. That will let us find them easier in the code later. Then I used a regex to figure out the menu name. You could make this a bit easier on yourself by using something like a `data-` attribute instead of having to deal with a regex (then you could just say something like `$(this).data("menu-name")` for example).

Instead of using `toggleClass` you'll want to hide all of them, then show the one you're interested in. That way you don't need to know which ones are already hidden or showing.

Below is the interesting code, but I've included it all in [an updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/redbmk/2zrjzdy3/1/) as well.

```js
$(".link").mouseenter(function() {
  var menuName = /\bselect-(\w+?)\b/.exec(this.className)[1];

  $(".link").removeClass("active rotated");
  $(this).addClass("active rotated");

  $(".menu").removeClass("show_menu");
  $("." + menuName + "_menu").addClass("show_menu");
});
```